# GetStringFileInfo Not Grabbing Last Character

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to make an installer for an application. In my .iss script I use `GetStringFileInfo(SourceDir + "\myapp\myapp.exe", PRODUCT_VERSION)` to get the "Product version" from the metadata of my exe. To be more specific I currently have:

```
#define MyAppVersion GetStringFileInfo(SourceDir + "\myapp\myapp.exe", PRODUCT_VERSION)
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```

Unfortunately, it seems to not be grabbing the last character of the product version and I can't figure out why. So for example if the product version is `1.1.1`, then in control panel I see `1.1.`.

I can confirm the value of product version by right clicking on the .exe and looking at the details, but when I look in control panel after installing the application the final character is missing.

I've tried replacing `PRODUCT_VERSION` with other metadata values such as `FILE_VERSION`, and that works perfectly. The issue only appears to be with `PRODUCT_VERSION`.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: In my case your code works fine for `PRODUCT_VERSION`. Perhaps you want to get `FILE_VERSION` instead of `PRODUCT_VERSION`?

Comment: Unfortunately we'd like to use `PRODUCT_VERSION`.

Comment: I have tested your code on several Executables and in all cases function returned full Product Version. Can you call `MsgBox` in `InitializeSetup` with `ExpandConstant('{#MyAppVersion}')` and post Screenshots with this message and another with File Properties (details tab)?

Comment: Or even better, provide us the `myapp.exe` for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for going so quite on this question! I had to move away from this problem for a bit. Turns out this was an issue with a library I was using, **electron-packager**, that appears to have been resolved by upgrading to the latest version. Although I couldn't find anything in their issue log which was related to this, it definitely appears to have been the problem. Thank you to all who spent time on this question.